# Selenium Python how to extract a class inside another class?

Tags: python, selenium, browser-automation

I'm web-scraping a page and I want to extract the information that a class has but the class is inside another class.

my code:

```
x = browser.find_element_by_id("resposta-situacao-eleitoral")
y = x.find_element_by_class_name("servicoeleitor-alert servicoeleitor-alert-warning")
```

code of the site:

```
<div id="resposta-situacao-eleitoral">
    <div class="servicoeleitor-alert servico-eleitor-alert-warning">
         "        Biometria não coletada
         "
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the selenium selector:

```py
x = browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#resposta-situacao-eleitoral > .servicoeleitor-alert.servico-eleitor-alert-warning")
```

Comment: give the same error of my solution "No such element"i don't know why is given this error

Comment: im trying to extract the "Biometria não coletada"

Comment: Hi @LuccaGontijo I actually missed something when I wrote my original answer, you might've missed the same thing, try what I've posted just now

Comment: @M.Z the same error im stuck on this for one week give the same error all time